# How can I add a custom button to the GIMP toolbar?

Tags: gimp, shortcuts

I'd like to be able to add custom buttons to the GIMP toolbar.

For example to be able to add the "Hue-Saturation Tool". There is a youtube video ([GIMP Tutorial: Customizing Main Tool Bar](https://youtu.be/3w0-5pjR2FM?t=201)) that shows how to do this in GIMP 2.4 via "Configure this tab"->Add Tab->Tools.

[image]

And then down to "Tools" option:

[image]

However in gimp 2.8.22 there is no "Tools" option in the pop-up menu. How do I add these tools in GIMP 2.8?

Answer (score 1):

Just realized this functionality is available via Edit -> Preferences -> Toolbox in GIMP 2.8

You can customize to add/hide tools and reorder them.